# Applying a function on specific Dataframe rows with datetime index as arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given the following Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd                                                              
from collections import OrderedDict                                              


d = OrderedDict([ ('Date_Time', ['2016-01-18 00:00:00', '2016-01-18 12:00:00', '2016-01-19 00:00:00', '2016-01-19 12:00:00']),
           ('Symbol', ['AUD', 'AUD', 'AUD', 'AUD']),                              
           ('Hit',  [False, False, True, False]),                                 
            ] )                                                                   
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)                                                   
df = df.set_index('Date_Time')  

print(df)
```

---

```
                    Symbol    Hit
Date_Time                        
2016-01-18 00:00:00    AUD  False
2016-01-18 12:00:00    AUD  False
2016-01-19 00:00:00    AUD   True
2016-01-19 12:00:00    AUD  False
```

How would one go about passing the ***Date_Time* index and the following** to a function only when **Hit** is *true* to then return the result of that same function to an other column ( say *Score* )

in this particular case in pseudo code :

```
    my_func(dt1, dt2):
        #do something on dt1 and d2
        return True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new column you could just do:

```
def dosomething(x, y):
    return something

df['New Column'] = dosomething(df_col1, df_col2)
```

This should create a new column with the logic dependent on those two columns.

Comment: nice and easy, but how would I feed my function with the Date_Time index(es) ?

Comment: That was pretty simple answering it myself ! dosomething(df.index, df_col2)